# how can I use magnetometer accelerometer data on IOS to determine the orientation of iphone

Tags: sensors, android-sensors

how can I use 3D magnetometer and accelerometer data on IOS to determine the orientation of smart phone ? Any links an reference will be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but as an answer is lacking, here is a [link to a blog post](http://rouel-projects.blogspot.com/p/calculations-with-iphones.html) that talks just about that.